# WPF DataTrigger Based on Color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatrigger

I'm trying to change the background of control A based on the background of control B, using a DataTrigger.

I've attempted to do this the conventional way you would change any property in a DataTrigger. Worst case I figure I can just use a converter, but wanted to try this first. Where have I gone astray, or is there simply no way to do this (i.e., bind to a control's background in a DataTrigger)?

```
            <Grid.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background, ElementName=Icon}" Value="Black">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen"></Setter>
                  </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
```

Comment: Hello, the approach you provided will work. So you can use this or ValueConverter

Comment: what is the problem? it works in my test.

Comment: I suppose the problem in your case is the fact, that you cannot override Background value, if it's defined as an attribute in control (in this case, in Grid). You should define default background value in Style section.